# php/mysql transaction not rolling back on failure (Codeigniter framework)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

below I have the following code. If the transaction fails, it is NOT being rolled back. If I remove the lock table statements it rolls back. Is there anything special I need to do in order to use locks and transactions?

```
function save ($items,$customer_id,$employee_id,$comment,$show_comment_on_receipt,$payments,$sale_id=false, $suspended = 0, $cc_ref_no = '', $auth_code = '', $change_sale_date=false,$balance=0, $store_account_payment = 0)
{
    if(count($items)==0)
        return -1;

    $sales_data = array(
        'customer_id'=> $this->Customer->exists($customer_id) ? $customer_id : null,
        'employee_id'=>$employee_id,
        'payment_type'=>$payment_types,
        'comment'=>$comment,
        'show_comment_on_receipt'=> $show_comment_on_receipt ?  $show_comment_on_receipt : 0,
        'suspended'=>$suspended,
        'deleted' => 0,
        'deleted_by' => NULL,
        'cc_ref_no' => $cc_ref_no,
        'auth_code' => $auth_code,
        'location_id' => $this->Employee->get_logged_in_employee_current_location_id(),
        'store_account_payment' => $store_account_payment,
    );

    $this->db->trans_start();

    //Lock tables invovled in sale transaction so we don't have deadlock
    $this->db->query('LOCK TABLES '.$this->db->dbprefix('customers').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales').' WRITE, 
    '.$this->db->dbprefix('store_accounts').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_payments').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').' WRITE, 
    '.$this->db->dbprefix('giftcards').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items').' WRITE, 
    '.$this->db->dbprefix('inventory').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_taxes').' WRITE,
    '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_item_kits').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_item_kits_taxes').' WRITE,'.$this->db->dbprefix('people').' READ,'.$this->db->dbprefix('items').' READ
    ,'.$this->db->dbprefix('employees_locations').' READ,'.$this->db->dbprefix('locations').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('items_tier_prices').' READ
    , '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items_tier_prices').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('items_taxes').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits').' READ
    , '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kit_items').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('employees').' READ , '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits_tier_prices').' READ
    , '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits_tier_prices').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items_taxes').' READ
    , '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits_taxes'). ' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits_taxes'). ' READ');


    $this->db->insert('sales',$sales_data);
    $sale_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    //A bunch of mysql other queries to save a sale


    $this->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return $sale_id;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's mainly beacuse of the fact that MySQL "LOCK TABLES" **commits any active transaction** *before* attempting to lock the tables.

Actually, the interaction between the two actions (LOCKING and TRANSACTIONS) looks quite tricky in MySQL, as it's very clearly and completely outlined in **[the MySQL manual page.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)**

The proposed solution is to turn OFF  the `autocommit` flag (which is ON by default, so usually every query issued is automatically committed after execution) by issueing the `SET autocommit = 0` command:

> The correct way to use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES with
>   transactional tables [..] is to begin a transaction with SET
>   autocommit = 0 (not START TRANSACTION) followed by LOCK TABLES, and to
>   not call UNLOCK TABLES until you commit the transaction explicitly.
>   For example, if you need to write to table t1 and read from table t2,
>   you can do this:

Your code could look like this:

```
$this->db->query("SET autocommit=0");
$this->db->query("LOCK TABLES...."); // your query here
$this->db->query("COMMIT");
$this->db->query("UNLOCK TABLES');
```

Comment: Just a follow up question. It seems even if I do this and there is an error, the transaction is partially committed. Is there a way to do this where the transaction is NOT committed if there is an error?