# transaction + rollback when using lock tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is a follow up to:
[php/mysql transaction not rolling back on failure (Codeigniter framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091918/php-mysql-transaction-not-rolling-back-on-failure-codeigniter-framework)

I implemented the suggested pattern at the above link. My questions are:

1. Do I need to do rollback every time a query fails? It seems I have to check each query for its result and then do a rollback if it fails. This seems kind of repetitive .

   ```
   $this->db->query("SET autocommit=0");

   //Lock tables invovled in sale transaction so we don't have deadlock
   $this->db->query('LOCK TABLES '.$this->db->dbprefix('customers').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales').' WRITE, 
   '.$this->db->dbprefix('store_accounts').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_payments').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').' WRITE, 
   '.$this->db->dbprefix('giftcards').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items').' WRITE, 
   '.$this->db->dbprefix('inventory').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_taxes').' WRITE,
   '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_item_kits').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_item_kits_taxes').' WRITE,'.$this->db->dbprefix('people').' READ,'.$this->db->dbprefix('items').' READ
   ,'.$this->db->dbprefix('employees_locations').' READ,'.$this->db->dbprefix('locations').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('items_tier_prices').' READ
   , '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items_tier_prices').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('items_taxes').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits').' READ
   , '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kit_items').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('employees').' READ , '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits_tier_prices').' READ
   , '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits_tier_prices').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items_taxes').' READ
   , '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits_taxes'). ' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits_taxes'). ' READ');

       if (!$this->db->insert('sales',$sales_data))
       {
           $this->db->query("ROLLBACK");
           $this->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');
           return -1;
       }
   ```

...
...

```
$this->db->query("COMMIT");         
$this->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

Comment: You should use exceptions as mechanism of catching the unwanted behaviour and then rollback. However, I see you're still using table locking and transactions, that ultimately defeats every good practice possible so I'll just wish you good luck and warn  you that you shouldn't lock your tables. Short answer - yes, roll back the failed transactions. Using PDO it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: I second N.B.'s suggestion of just on big try / catch loop & setting up the database connection to throw exceptions on failure. And why would you lock those tables, for what purpose is that exactly? It scales... terribly. Deadlocks are usually fixed by fixing the queries causing a deadlock, use `show engine innodb status` to see why a deadlock occurred (and if you have a lot of them, run something like `pt-deadlock-logger` for a while).

Comment: Unfortunately codeigniter does not have exception handling as that would be the easiest. Is there any other way? In regards to dead locking; I would rather avoid the deadlock, then attempt to restart the transaction. It is very important that this part of the program works without error. Every user has their own database so it wouldn't affect everyone; just that one company/user. What is the problem with looking besides other connections will have to wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get away from using `LOCK TABLES` and `UNLOCK TABLES;` because it can trigger implicit commits. Instead, you should look into using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARED MODE`.

If you are using MySQL 5.6, try starting the transaction with

- `START TRANSACTION READ WRITE;`
- `START TRANSACTION READ ONLY;`

I wrote about this in the DBA StackExchange (See [row locking within ACID transaction innodb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58712/877))

If you still wish to use `LOCK TABLES;` and `UNLOCK TABLES`, keep in mind that `LOCK TABLES` starts a new transaction, `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT` are still mandatory because `UNLOCK TABLES;` triggers an implicit commit. `ROLLBACK` gives you the opportunity to throw away changes the transaction was holding. `UNLOCK TABLES;` will commit changes you probably wanted to undo.

The only implicit rollback is the termination of a DB Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has built-in transactions support, You don't need to do these manually.

And I believe it was improved in CodeIgniter v3 (Still in development).

Basically, All you have to do is something like this:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Calling trans_complete() will automatically roll-back when there's a failed query.

If you want to handle errors yourself, You'll do something like this:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Please keep in mind I am referring to CodeIgniter v3 which you can get it off github as I ditched the CodeIgniter v2 over a year ago.

Comment: It you look at the question a bit more carefully you will see I am using lock tables and regular transactions don't work because of this which is why I have the workaround